# How to fetch Persons on multiple teams with different P1 ratings in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
TABLE 1                                   Table 2(Team Ratings)

ID   Teamid       Team                  Teamid      Ratings
--------------------------              -------------------
1    TeamA        null                  TeamA       R1
2    Steve        TeamA                 TeamB       P1
3    Jacob        TeamA                 TeamC       Q1
4    Dierken      TeamA
5    TeamB        null
6    Julie        TeamB
7    Jacob        TeamB
8    Raki         null
9    Balmer       TeamC
```

May anyone help with this please. I would like to fetch all the rows from Table1 whose Person condition is "Persons on Team A with R1 ratings and the same person on different team with P1 ratings or any other ratings.

Output should be like

```
id    TEamid      Team      Ratings
------------------------------------
1     Jacob       TeamA        R1
2     Jacob       TeamB        P1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the people using aggregation.  However, your description doesn't require the second table, because it is pretty much "get people on TeamA and another team".

```
select t1.teamid
from table1 t1 
group by t1.teamid
having count(distinct t1.team) = 2;
```

For more complete results, you can join the data together and use window functions:

```
with t as (
      select t1.*, t2.rating
      from table1 t1 join
           table2 t2
           on t1.team = t2.teamid
     )
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when team = 'TeamA' and rating = 'R1' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by teamid) as a_match,
             sum(case when team <> 'TeamA' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by teamid) as other_match
      from t
     ) t
where a_match > 0 and other_match > 0;
```

Comment: @Linoff. Thank you so much for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This would be another option:

```
CREATE TABLE Teams
(
    ID  INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
    ,Teamid VARCHAR(50)
    ,Team   varchar(50)
)
GO

INSERT INTO TeamsRaitings
VALUES('TeamA','R1')
      ,('TeamB','P1')

INSERT INTO teams
VALUES('TeamA',nULL)
,('Steve','TeamA')
,('Jacob','TeamA')
,('Dierken','TeamC')
,('Steve','TeamA')
,('TeamB',nULL)
,('Julie','TeamB')
,('Jacob','TeamB')
,('Raki',NULL)
,('Balmer','TeamC')


;WITH TeamA AS (
SELECT a.ID
      ,a.Teamid
      ,a.Team
      ,  raiting = CASE WHEN TEAM IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE  'R1' END 
 FROM teams a
  WHERE A.Team = 'TeamA' OR A.Team IS NULL
 ),
 AnotherTEam AS (
SELECT  a.ID
      ,a.Teamid
      ,a.Team
      ,raiting = 'P1'
 FROM teams a
  WHERE A.Team <> 'TeamA'
   AND EXISTS (SELECT top 1 1 FROM TeamA where A.Teamid= TeamA.Teamid)
 )

 SELECT ID
        ,Teamid
        ,Team
        ,raiting

  FROM TeamA
  UNION all
  SELECT ID
        ,Teamid
        ,Team
        ,raiting
  FROM ANOTHERTEAM
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the Answer. I wil go through it.